# .NET Community Toolkit Messaging - Registering with Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, windows-community-toolkit

I am experimenting with the [.NET Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) `IMessenger` interface in a Blazor Server application.

It appears a singleton service is utilized which is not ideal as the messages are shared across all connected sessions. This causes the behavior shown in the gif below. The count in the sidebar is incrementing across all browser tabs/sessions.

Is it possible to use the `WeakReferenceMessenger` and/or the `StrongReferenceMessenger` in a Blazor Server application registered with a [transient](https://chrissainty.com/service-lifetimes-in-blazor/) service lifetime?

##### Sender

```cs
private void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new IncrementCountMessage(currentCount));
}
```

##### Receiver

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorServerSandbox;

public partial class Receiver : ComponentBase, IRecipient<IncrementCountMessage>
{
    public int CurrentCount { get; set; } = 0;

    public Receiver()
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register(this);
    }

    public void Receive(IncrementCountMessage message)
    {
        CurrentCount = message.Value;
        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your Program/Startup class:

```
services.AddScoped<IMessenger, WeakReferenceMessenger>();
```

then in your components/pages inject IMessenger and use like:
receiver:

```
[Inject] IMessenger Messenger
Messenger.Register<MyMessage>(this, (r, m) => DoSomthing());
```

sender:

```
[Inject] IMessenger Messenger
Messenger.Send(new MyMessage("test"));
```

Hope this help.